# How to set up a custom timeout on giving back the connection from pool? (Logon Storm)

Tags: java, connection-pooling, c3p0

I use c3p0 pool connection. By default the connection will be returned from the pool almost immediately. I want to set up a custom timeout on giving back the connection when we reached the limit of active connections. Perhaps someone knows how i can do this?

```
minConnections: 5
maxConnections: 100
limit: 20
```

When the application will ask 21th connection, pool will return its only after 3 seconds of waiting.

The one approach which i know is to extend an abstract class AbstractComboPooledDataSource and override method getConnection():

```
@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
      if(getNumConnections() >= limitConnectionsOfWaiting) {
          sleepThread(3) //3 seconds
      }
      return super.getConnection();
}
```

P.S I'm trying to solve the problem "logon storm".

Comment: How can putting a connectio back into the pool, from whence you got it, breach the limit of active connections? The time to check that is when you *create* a connection, presumably by first looking in the pool.

Comment: Maybe try to use `initialPoolSize`. As mentioned I doubt there is anything like this in stock c3p0.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [checkoutTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#checkoutTimeout) setting in C3P0 that is probably what you need:

> The number of milliseconds a client calling getConnection() will wait for a Connection to be checked-in or acquired when the pool is exhausted. Zero means wait indefinitely. Setting any positive value will cause the getConnection() call to time-out and break with an SQLException after the specified number of milliseconds.

Comment: I saw this setting, but it's not that i'm looking for. checkoutTimeout is used only when the pool is exhausted. In my case, we didn't reach the max limit of connections

Comment: You want all requests to wait for a certain amount of time even if there are still connections available? I doubt that there is a feature in c3p0 for this, as I don't see any practical use for this. BTW. what do you mean by "limit of active connections" reached? There doesn't seem to be a settings for this in c3p0 either and it's more related to the database backend itself.

Comment: I edited my question.  Active connections are those which weren't close yet and still available in the pool for reusing.